# Jquery image or url in div data-

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to change 'data-description' to like div class? But still make the script working, because I want to put a url and image in data-description

Please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#MenuBar1 div").mouseover(function() {
            $('.description').text($(this).data('description'));
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <div data-description="Beschrijving 1">
    <a href="#">Titel 1</a>
    </div>

    <div data-description="Beschrijving 2">
    <a href="#">Titel 2</a>
    </div>

    <div data-description="Beschrijving 3">
    <a href="#">Titel 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
Text change.
</div>
```

Comment: what is `#back` and who is changing the value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('#elementID').data('description','urlyou want');
```

Comment: When I hover over Titel 1.. Beschrijving 1 shows in div .description. When I hover over Titel 2.. Beschrijving 2 shows in div description etc. But I can't put any a href tags of images in data-description (that will show in div .description). How can I do that?